# How do I secure a vinyl window to the wall?

Tags: windows, installation

When installing my vinyl windows should I put a nail into every little hole around the window? It has a flange that has many little holes around it. Also what size nails would you recommend? Finally do I need to secure the window to the inside of the rough opening, as you do with a door?

Comment: This question should be edited to reflect new construction installation versus replacement windows.  My answer below is based on replacement windows.  The installation methods differ.

Comment: He talks about the nailing fin ("flange") in the question - so these are not replacement, they are new contrustion windows.

Comment: Answers are dependent on window brand and type. Some have more closely spaced nailing slots and don't call for nails in every one. RTFM. Voting to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes put a nail into every hole.  I would recommend galvanized nails that are 1 to 2 inches in length.  If there is nothing behind the flange but plywood, anything over an inch and the nail will just be sticking through the plywood.

I assume you will hit some framing behind the playwood, so a little longer and you will hit that.  I looked over my new vinyl windows in my sunroom and there are no attachment points on the inside of the window.

I don't recall doing anything on the inside of the window when installing.  The most important point I remember was with the flashing on the outside.  Start at the bottom, then the sides, then the top so that water can be properly channelled away.  There is a video below in the comments showing an installation.  I remember it was pretty straight forward, just made sure the windows are level.

Comment: The windows I am installing is in a new rough opening, no pre-existing windows.

Comment: OK, for new rough opening it is definatley different than replacement windows.

Comment: This is for new windows.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j8xY5QKVU9s&feature=related , I would fill every hole, looks like a 1.5" galvanized nail.

Comment: If you have the model number off this window, go to the manufacturer's website and look up their installation instructions. Milgard, Jeld-Wen, et.al. are pretty explicit in how to install a window so it meets their warranty. Usually, they want you to use roofing nails and put them in every other hole. Vinyl expands and contracts, this allows for it to happen. There's a flexible flashing and caulk routine as well to prevent leaks.

Comment: Rarely are that many nails necessary, even per the instructions. The high number of slots is offered for versatility as much as anything. Yes, follow the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

From personal experience, installing a nail in every hole is wasting time and materiel.  Most instructions recommend every other hole, which will cover any unlikely warranty issues.

A good resource for this question can be found at [This Old House](http://www.thisoldhouse.com/toh/how-to/intro/0,,218006,00.html).  I find that "This Old House" is a great resource for learning the proper way to accomplish construction tasks.  Keep in mind that they do not share any shortcuts...

Comment: I agree. With nails of adequate length that would be absurd overkill.

Answer (score -1):

For new construction (I.e. Windows with vinyl flange) I highly recommend Vinyl window attached from the outside the window opening. This means the vinyl flange will be on the outside.  Measure the whole placement on the flange, then by marking the inside wall, carefully drive a 6 inch timber screw through each hole. This means you will be driving the 6 inch timber screw through the inside out. You need at least 6 inches to make it through the 2 x 6 framing around the window. An eighth of an inch sticking through the window. Then place a washer on each screw tip. Use aluminum foil on top of the washer so hold it in place. If the screws are sticking out too far to finish with trim, you can use a hard disk grinder to grind down the tips. This normally takes me 2 to 3 hours per window. However I don’t know the proper way to install windows. I actually recommend just leaving the window opening open without glass. Trust me, this will save a lot of headache. Some people put louvers on their window opening.

Comment: "I don't know the proper way to install windows", but I'll offer a random assortment of very odd advice? Hmm.

Comment: Troll is trolling.